# How to return a value by matching a cell (string) to a range of pre-fixes

Tags: excel, search, indexing, match

I haven't seen this question asked before so I am hopeful that this might be something new to get your teeth into and assit me with a thorny problem.

I have a list of over 13K values in a column which are locations. let's call it Column A.

These locations cannot be sorted, and are a mixture of single values and multiple values. e.g. 1A-01R or 1B-04L, 4C-3D, 094-01F, TOR-5-A, TOR-F.

In another column I have placed in the spreadsheet which is a list of these locations broken down by prefix, approx 80 distinct values. Let's call it Column B.

Next to Column B I have a list of descriptions for each pre-fix location, e.g. Bins, Racks Yard, Floor etc. Let's Call this Column C.

The issue I have been banging my head against, is how to search for the value in Column A in the list of pre-fixes in Column B and return the corresponding value in C?

It seems Excel loves to seach an incomplete value against a list of complete values but if you try to reverse the logic, you get errors.

I've tried using vlookup, index and match to no avail.

A small example. A = 13k+ lines, B = 80 lines, c= 80 lines

```
Column A  Column B  Column C   Column D
AREA 5      1A-     RACKS      Formula? = check A against range in column B and return C
094-10G     1B-     RACKS
1J-H0L      1C-     RACKS
099-03A     1D-     RACKS
098-03C     1E-     RACKS
1L-F2R      1F-     RACKS
1K-L5L      1G-     RACKS
1C-D5R      1H-     RACKS
AREA 5      1I-     RACKS
1F-L4L      1J-     RACKS
1F-L4L      W5E-    RACKS
W5-E7       W5-     FLOOR
W5-E7       098-    RACKS
W5-E7       099-    BINS
W5E-01L     AREA    FLOOR
```

Update 1

OK so based upon the proposals i think we are close to a solution.

I have used the following formula in Column D that appears to always work and returns the value in Column B.

{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$91,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$B$2:$B$91&"*"),0)),"")}

This is an array formula, so i'm using ctrl+shift+enter.

Now all we need to do is get this formula to return the value in Column C and I think we are almost there.

There is one more part to the issue which might be a step to far, which is to return multiple values to the formula cell, in the intances there is more than 1 location stored in the cell in Column A.

Update 2.

OK we have a working formula that checks the contents of Column A against the range in Column B and returns in Column D, the value stored in Column C! =)

the array formula is: {=VLOOKUP(IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$91,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A3,""&$B$2:$B$91&""),0)),""),B:C,2,FALSE)}

```
location                        pre-fix            loc type
W5-E3       
W5-E3,W5-E4     
W5-B6       
W5-A4       
W50-01      
W5N-02R, W5-N5R,W5X-02L     
W5K-00R, W5-L0R     
W50-01      
W5-C6       
W5-AA01L        
W5-F5       
W5-A4,W5-E5,W5-C3,W5-A3     
W5-C5,W5-B6     
W5-C1       
W5H-04,W5H-03,W5-D4,W5G-00,W5-A1        
W5-D7       
W5V-00
```

Here's the big question, it is possible to find and return each instance a location is found in a cell in Column A in a single cell of Column D?

Comment: Update your question with one or two examples of column **B** values please.

Comment: sample data has been added.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to extract the prefix from the data in column `A`.  Assuming the delimiter is either a space or a dash, you can do that with this formula:

`=LEFT(A2,IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",A2)),FIND(" ",A2)-1,FIND("-",A2)))`

Then you can use `VLOOKUP` to search for this in column `B` and return the value in column `C`.  You can embed the above function in the `VLOOKUP` to create a single formula:

`=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",A2)),FIND(" ",A2)-1,FIND("-",A2))),B$2:C$16,2,FALSE)`

On the data above, this gives some `#N/A` values - these are where the prefix extracted from column `A` doesn't exist in your list in column `B`.

```
    Column A    Column D
    AREA 5      FLOOR
    094-10G     #N/A
    1J-H0L      RACKS
    099-03A     #N/A
    098-03C     #N/A
    1L-F2R      RACKS
    1K-L5L      RACKS
    1C-D5R      RACKS
    AREA 5      FLOOR
    1F-L4L      RACKS
    1F-L4L      RACKS
    W5-E7       #N/A
    W5-E7       #N/A
    W5-E7       #N/A
    W5-E7       #N/A
```

Update 1

OK so based upon the proposals i think we are close to a solution.

I have used the following formula in Column `D` that appears to always work and returns the value in Column `B`.

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$91,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$B$2:$B$91&"*"),0)),"")}`

This is an array formula, so i'm using `ctrl`+`shift`+`enter`.

Now all we need to do is get this formula to return the value in Column `C` and I think we are almost there.

There is one more part to the issue which might be a step to far, which is to return multiple values to the formula cell, in the intances there is more than 1 location stored in the cell in Column `A`.

Update 2.

OK we have a working formula that checks the contents of Column A against the range in Column B and returns in Column D, the value storeds in Column C! =)

the array formula is: {=VLOOKUP(IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$91,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A3,"*"&$B$2:$B$91&"*"),0)),""),B:C,2,FALSE)}

```
location          pre-fix     loc type
W5-E3       
W5-E3,W5-E4     
W5-B6       
W5-A4       
W50-01      
W5N-02R, W5-N5R,W5X-02L     
W5K-00R, W5-L0R     
W50-01      
W5-C6       
W5-AA01L        
W5-F5       
W5-A4,W5-E5,W5-C3,W5-A3     
W5-C5,W5-B6     
W5-C1       
W5H-04,W5H-03,W5-D4,W5G-00,W5-A1        
W5-D7       
W5V-00
```

Here's the big question, it is possible to find and return each instance a location is found in a cell in Column A in a single cell of Column D?

Comment: This looks Good Steve, however...I have location that are TOR-A3 and TOR-5-A. How would you get around the double -? after all the issue tis then that your can't differentiate between TOR- or TOR-5-XYZ...

Comment: Ok Darren, so is it the case that there can be one or two dashes, and if there are two then the prefix is the part up to and including the second dash?  So, for TOR-A3 it is 'TOR-', and for TOR-5-A it is 'TOR-5-'?  If so, the following will work: =VLOOKUP(LEFT(B2,IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",B2)),FIND(" ",B2)-1,FIND("-",B2,IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",B2,FIND("-",B2)+1)),1,FIND("-",B2,FIND("-",B2)+1))))),C$2:D$16,2,FALSE).  This is getting a bit clumsy though!  If you've got any more cases, it would be better to post the complete set so we can work out a formula to cover all eventualities.

Comment: Would you be happy with a VBA function?  It's getting quite complex to do it in a single Excel formula.

Comment: Hi Steve, I thought about VBA but I will be leaving this sheet in the hands of non-coders, so if this can be achieved in a formula, so much the better. and I see I didn't update the main post, but your answer instead lol!

Comment: Ok, I understand.  A VBA function might end up being more user friendly in the end though, as very long nested formulas become difficult to edit and troubleshoot...  How about adding additional columns to break it down (these could be hidden if required)?  On your specific question about multiple instances, I see these are sometimes separated by a comma and sometimes by a comma then a space.  Are these the only alternatives?  Is there a maximum possible number of locations in a single cell?

Comment: HI Steve, in the end the number of cells with multiple location references is small, less than 1%, so I've decided to manually override these. I think it was a little too much to ask for and is somewhat like mission creep. I'll mark the question as answered and update it witht he working formula. Many thanks for the help though, much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome Darren, I'm glad you've got the answers you were looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just isolate the prefix part of column **A** and use it in the *VLOOKUP()*.  In **D1** enter:

```
=VLOOKUP(IF(LEFT(A1,4)="AREA","AREA",MID(A1,1,FIND("-",A1))),B:C,2,FALSE)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: The problem I have is that the prefix varies in A, In your example it looks good but in the scope of what i'm looking at, i keep getting #N/a errors for values I know I have pre-fixes for. The closest I got to with this was by using index and match but even then, it threw up false positives.

Comment: as I mentioned in the other solution, I have locations like W5-A3 or W5A-01L or TOR-A4, TOR-5-A. These are skipped by both proposed solutions.

Comment: @DarrenDawson  I think we are about 80% there.......   **update your original Post with cases the formula does not handle and we can make adjustments!**

Comment: I've made more data available and provided a working formula to return the a value using index. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

OK we have a working formula that checks the contents of Column A against the range in Column B and returns in Column D, the value storeds in Column C! =)

the array formula is:

```
{=VLOOKUP(IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$91,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A3,""&$B$2:$B$91&""),0)),""),B:C,2,FALSE)}
```